# How to set up a NAT and and a Host Only adapter using Vagrant?

Tags: virtualbox, centos, ruby, vagrant

I am trying to make a NAT connection (for yum downloads) and a Host-Only connection (for talking with host) at the same time on my CentOS box when using Vagrant.

I **CAN** do it by  SSHing and checking `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and creating corresponding `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1`. However I can't find anything describing how to have both a NAT and a HOST only connection in Vagrant using Vagrantfile configurations. Things to consider:

1. Bridged connection is NOT what I want. I'm behind a DHCP client that requires authentication.
2. `config.vm.network :hostonly, "192.168.50.4"` overwrites the default NAT connection, so that does not work either.

Thanks in advance for sharing your know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `:adapter` parameter to achieve what you want. Keep in mind that the adapter no. 1 is always a NAT.

```
config.vm.network :hostonly, "192.168.50.4", :adapter => 2
```

Comment: this is not for latest vagrant is it?